# JS Code running very slow

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am a JS novice so go easy on me here. But I wrote a simple slideshow and it seems to be running very slow. The code below takes about 2-4 seconds to load locally on my own machine. Wondering what is causing the delay. Let me know, thanks!

```
function slideshow(){
    $("#1").animate({top: "50px",}, 500).delay(2000);
    $("#1").animate({top: "400px",}, 500);
    $("#2").animate({top: "50px",}, 500).delay(2000);
    $("#2").animate({top: "400px",}, 500);
    $("#3").animate({top: "50px",}, 500).delay(2000);
    $("#3").animate({top: "400px",}, 500);
    $("#4").animate({top: "50px",}, 500).delay(2000);
    $("#4").animate({top: "400px",}, 500);
    $("#5").animate({top: "50px",}, 500).delay(2000);
    $("#5").animate({top: "400px",}, 500);
    slideshow();
}
```

Each ID represents a different image.

Comment: Well, I would expect that to take 13 seconds in total. What is it doing?

Comment: Those `delay` calls are not delaying the execution of the next statement (if that was your intend). Also, the `slideshow` call at the end pretty much executes immediately (the preceding statements are non-blocking).

Comment: Maybe the fact that the script  loads all the images before running the function?

Comment: Here is what my end goal is: http://tinyurl.com/ckk3rhb ... only tested in chrome... should work fine in safari

Comment: probably not the image size, as he mentioned he is running on his local, unless those are some humongous pictures :x And judging on the stuff u run in that script, it's more like a timing issue instead of performance issue, even IE8 or lower can handle that couple lines of script ok.

Comment: Please do not post tiny URLs (or any other of their ilk). Most here want to assume we know what we're clicking on before we do so. `:)` If you can, make a http://jsfiddle.net.

Comment: For instance, here is a fiddle with the information you have given: http://jsfiddle.net/KchG3/

Comment: The id's of HTML elements are not supposed to start with numbers.

Comment: http://www.hdesignonline.com/qdup/ ... don't want to take the time to set up a jsfiddle...

Comment: never mind, just figured out The slideshow() inside the slideshow() is execute immediately after it's being called, thus... no delay infinitely loop.

Comment: @David - Numeric ids are (officially) fine in html5, but even older browsers are fairly forgiving about that sort of thing. Are you aware of a browser where they don't work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The *big* problem with your code, since none of the other answers seem to have talked about it yet, is that the last line of `slideshow()` calls itself recursively, which will lead to a stack overflow. Don't do this:

```
function slideshow() {
   // animate code
   slideshow();
}
```

Instead, if you want it to run repeatedly, use `setTimeout()` to queue another execution of the function *x* milliseconds later:

```
function slideshow() {
   // animate code
   setTimeout(slideshow, 3500);
}
```

The way you had it, none of the functions ever actually finishes. With `setTimeout()`, each invocation of `slideshow()` does finish, and then a separate one runs after the specified delay. I'd make the delay big enough that the next invocation occurs after the current animations finish, otherwise you'll be queuing up more and more animations faster than they run.

**UPDATE:** jQuery maintains separate animation queues for each element, which means that the animations on your five elements will run simultaneously. Some of the other answers already provide ways of running the animations in sequence one at a time, but here is how I'd do it:

```
$(window).on("load",function() {    
    // cache a jQuery object containing the elements to animate
    // (note you don't need their ids if you use their class)
    var $imgs = $('img.slideshow-image'),
        i = 0;

    function slideShow() {
       // start animation for "current" img
       $imgs.eq(i).show(1)
                  .animate({top: "50px",}, 500)
                  .delay(2000)
                  .animate({top: "400px",}, 500)
                  .hide(1, function() {
                     i = (i+1) % $imgs.length;
                     setTimeout(slideShow, 500);
                  });
    }    
    slideShow();    
});
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/bARwb/

- I've wrapped the code in a load handler both to remove the need for an inline `onload=` attribute and as a convenient way of keeping the code out of the global scope (if you do it this way don't forget to remove `onload="slideShow()"` from your body tag).
- I've added `.show()` and `.hide()` calls (*with* a duration so that they join the animation queue) so that the img elements will have `display:none` in between animations because otherwise with your `position:relative` style you can't see any but the first (but changing to `position:absolute` would prevent them getting cropped by their parent's `overflow:hidden`).
- When the animation finishes for an element, the callback from `.hide()` increments `i` to refer to the next element's index (but checks for when it goes past the last element) and then uses `setTimeout()` to queue the animation for that next element.

Comment: Wow, brilliant, that works great. Is there anything else wrong with my code that I should be fixing, or can I run with this? Thanks!

Comment: If it now behaves as you want then no further changes are _needed_, but it would be more efficient to chain the second `.animate()` call for each element on the end of its `.delay()`, i.e.: `$("#1").animate({top: "50px",}, 500).delay(2000).animate({top: "400px",}, 500);` and similar for the other elements - calling `$("#1")` twice has to select the element and create a jQuery object twice.

Comment: It was mentioned. I even made a comment on it, with the exact error? Also, and this is just my opinion, but @nate8684 should *definitely* start to consider using caches for his repetitively called selectors. It's even more critical when making animations to have a caching strategy, and otherwise, it's just good practice, and this script clearly does that over and over.

Comment: Hi @JaredFarrish - yes, I saw your comment (and upvoted it), but my point was that none of the _answers_ explained the issue. The answer you commented on didn't even say it was a problem, it just mentioned it was "strange". If it were my code then yes, I'd cache the jQuery objects, and I'd run the code from a document.ready handler rather than an inline `onload`, but it's not actually "wrong" to not make those inprovements and I didn't want to make my answer too long.

Comment: P.S. given that the current code animates all the elements simultaneously with the same animation parameters I'd probably do it in one line as: `$("#1,#2,#3,#4,#5").animate({top: "50px",}, 500).delay(2000).animate({top: "400px",}, 500);` - or, better, give the elements a common class and select on that.

Comment: Fair enough, the way I originally read the statement was that nobody else spotted it, but you do specify the answer. I put the caching bit in there for the OP; it's so important when working with animation (and to only a somewhat lesser degree, non-animation) code that you *cache your selectors*, and the ones you're calling maybe only once but strategically? Precache, or something. Just don't overlook it. That could easily be part of an underlying problem in some animations.

Comment: Also, on another note, I'd just like to find a clean and succinct looping iterator technique to use with arrays. Y'know, like `$myImages.nextOrFirst()` or `arr.push(arr.reverse().pop())`. Hmm, that last would work if it returned a reference to the last value I just popped to the front.

Comment: Hey, I'm noticing that your code just keeps animating the first image...at least that's what it looks like. Any idea why it's not showing rotating through the images? http://www.hdesignonline.com/qdup/

Comment: I just took at look at your site and it seems like you've got it sorted using a different method. Are you still having problems? (Your original question didn't specify that the animations were supposed to happen one after the other, and without seeing the page I thought it reasonable that they were all supposed to happen at once - but if you're still having problems I could take a look.)

Comment: Yeah, I was trying out a different method. I do need the animations to occur on of another, creating a slideshow of sorts. I'm gathering that the animations are all firing at once? I need them to occur in succession, as soon as the animation completes it needs to fire the next one. Thoughts on how I could accomplish this? Thanks!

Comment: Any thoughts on how I can salvage this code...would love for each animation to fire after the previous.

Comment: Brilliant, thank you so much for your help for this js novice!

Answer (score 2):

You have some duplication in there, and also some incorrect assumptions.

When you call `.animate` in jQuery, you can specify a callback that will be called when the animation is complete. This is the place to put your "next step".

So in this example:

- animate the image
- when complete, wait 2 seconds
- after 2 seconds, animate the image
- when complete, call the function with the next image

This is how it looks

```
var images = ['#1', '#2', '#3', '#4', '#5'];

function slideshow(index){
    if (index >= images.length) {
        index = 0;
    }
    var image = images[index];
    $(image).animate({top: "50px",}, 500, function () {
        window.setTimeout(function () {
            $(image).animate({top: "400px",}, 500, function () {
                slideshow(index + 1);
            });
        }, 2000);
    });
}
```

Comment: Please, PLEASE, use caches of the element selectors. It's just good practice when looping over the same element over and over and over and over...

Comment: I tried posting the code and it doesn't seem to work...I'm looking into why it may not be working. No errors are coming through. I'm calling the function on the body onload="slideshow();" ... is that correct? Also, what's the meaning of the "index" in slideshow(index)?

Answer (score 0):

my guess is that you are setting your frames to 2 seconds (2000). Try something speedier like 50 and see what you see. I'm not sure if that's the frame delay or the 500 but if either of those represents how long you are waiting between frame changes it's way too long.

Comment: 500 is the length of the animation. 2000 is the delay before..well..doing nothing, because there's nothing in the queue after it.

Comment: no, it only delays the statement it chains to. if you want to delay progressively you do something like $.delay(2000,function(){}) and within that delay you call another delay. can't think of the right code out of my head, but something similar

Comment: @nate8684 - the delay will delay the next animation _on the same element_, but not animations on other elements.

Comment: @GängTian - you don't have to chain the statements for `.delay()` to work, as long as you remember that it only delays animations on the element(s) in the jQuery object it is called on, not for all animations on all elements.

Answer (score 0):

Other than the intentional delays in your code, i do not see anything that would cause the slow loading.  It may be the rest of the page.  I would check to see how large your images are and any other files that may be downloading before the JavaScript slideshow function executes.

As a side note, it is strange that you call slideshow from within the slideshow function.

Comment: That is actually the problem. It's recursing

Comment: The size of the example image is 113KB, as seen on the example provided by the Question opener

Comment: Yes, this is true. My test fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KchG3/ runs into stack overruns, `Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`, and putting a `console.log()` in there just bogs Chrome down like a 78 Buick in a Louisiana dirt parking lot.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
var intervalValue = setInterval( "slideshow()", 2000 );
var slideshow_imageindex = 1;

function slideshow()
{
  //check if imageindex is greater than the number of images available (5 is an example)
  if (slideshow_imageindex > 5)
  {
    slideshow_imageindex = 1;
  }
  //hide image below, change image src, then move image so that it is visible again
  $("#1").animate({top: "400px",}, 500).attr('src','img/Slideshow-Audio-Trsfr'+slideshow_imageindex+'.png').animate({top: "50px",}, 500);
  //increase image index
  slideshow_imageindex++;
}
```

You will only need a single img (i kept your "id=#1" img), and every 2 seconds the image is hidden, it changes and the it is shown again. Only things you have to do: name the images so that only the number changes, like:

```
img/Slideshow-Audio-Trsfr1.png
img/Slideshow-Audio-Trsfr2.png
img/Slideshow-Audio-Trsfr3.png
img/Slideshow-Audio-Trsfr4.png
img/Slideshow-Audio-Trsfr5.png
```

and then use the number of images in the "if" within the function. It's late here in italy, hope i didn't forget anything :)

Comment: Hey, I'm fiddling around with the slideshow, however I'm finding that the pause is at the incorrect spot. It pauses at the bottom, instead of at the top. Any idea how I might fix this?

Comment: That's after I modified the code a bit. The unedited code you gave me, had the pause in the right spot (top), but it also changed the image at the top, instead of at the bottom like I'd like it too.

Comment: Below seemed to work, however now the problem is that when you're in an actual online setting, the images don't load quickly enough to show. Thoughts?

Comment: $("#1").animate({top: "400px",}, 500, function () { $(this).attr('src','img/Slideshow-Audio-Trsfr'+slideshow_imageindex+'.png') }).animate({top: "50px",}, 500);

Comment: I see you are asking these questions 3 hours after you choose the correct answer. Didn't the solution you chose work?

Comment: I am running into some issues with that solution...found the issues after selecting it as correct. But I am interested in your solution as it seems a bit more efficient.

Comment: you could try putting a `.delay(1000)` before `.animate({top: "50px",}, 500);`. I must confess i use a different soltion on my own site, loading the first image at page load, then loading next image in an hidden div. When the slideshow need to change image, i just move the second image to the first div, and load the next image to the hidden one. This way, when the slideshow is running, next image is already loaded and there are no delay :)